# Passing NSString between classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, inheritance

this is something I have always had confusion about

I never can seem to find a good explanation, i understand inheritance, but from what i learned that is between the master class and the sublasses of them...What if i want to pass a NSString to another class thats not a subclass of the other

Heres a example:

class1.h

```
@interface class1 : UIViewController{
NSString *string
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string
@end
```

class1.m

```
@implementation class1
@synthesize string;
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 string = @"IM A STRING AHHH";
 }
```

Now lets say i want to pass that string with what its equal to to another class

```
class2.h

#import "class1.h"
@interface class2 : UIViewController{


}

@end


class2.m

@implementation class2 

//i want to use the NSString in here, how do i do that?
```

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use `[string retain];` in class 1.
Then, in class 2, import class1. make object of class 1 say cls1. and you can access it by `cls1.string;`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of `class1` and then you can access `string` simply calling

```
 [instance string];
```

or

```
 instance.string
```

If you don't want to create an instance of `class1` you may define a method such as

```
+(NSString*)getString;
```

and then call it from `class2`

```
[class1 getString];
```

Comment: Class1 already has -(NSString*)getString from the property - note it should be an instance method and return a NSString*

Comment: As you said, it is an instance method. Defining `+(NSString*)getString` you won't need to create an instance of `class1` to get the string.

Comment: But a class method cannot get the value of a property on the instance

Comment: But if the string is constant it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Smiriti's answer is right...

what else you can do is..

overrirde the `init` method and pass your `NSString` as a parameter and use it.

Answer (score 1):

If class 2 is loading from class 1 you can send the value as parameters.

```
-(id)initwithParameters:(NSString *)parameter
{

    if(self == [super init])
    {
        // access the paramenter and store in yo u avariable    
    }
    return self;

}
```

In class 1

```
[[class 2 alloc]initwithParameters: ]
```